# Jupyter-notebook can't do indentation

Tags: jupyter-notebook

why I can't use indentation and always automatically get the new line as the image below when I hit "enter", how could I change it to be indented?
[Preview error indentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xCIp.png)

Answer (score 0):

It might be the editor you are using or extensions you've installed.
You can press "tab" to manually indent the code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).